# Torsion subgroups of finitely generated abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

What information one can get about the torsion subgroups from a short exact sequence of finitely generated abelian groups ?

Answer (score 2):

At least one thing you can get from an exact sequence of abelian groups $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is the exact sequence of abelian groups
$$
0\to \mathrm{Tor}_1^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},A)\to \mathrm{Tor}_1^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},B)\to \\
\mathrm{Tor}_1^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},C)\to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}A\to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}B\to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}C\to 0
$$
The upshot is that $\mathrm{Tor}_1^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},X)$ is the torsion subgroup of $X$ for any abelian group $X$.

Comment: The Q/Z (x) A = (Q/Z)^n term is likely to make this not very useful. Q/Z is extremely receptive and its quotients all look the same. However, there isn't much relation between the torsion subgroups of A,B,C so this might be as good as it gets.

Comment: In particular you still get an exact sequence $0\to \mathrm{Tors}(A)\to\mathrm{Tors}(B)\to\mathrm{Tors}(C)$....